# Oracle select random rows matching a join condition

Tags: oracle, performance, join, random, sample

My objective is simple, I have to create a temporary table with some random values from a employee table whenever the department is in some particular department (say 2). For the rest of departments I don't care the value, it can be `NULL`.

Currently I have the following :

```
create table test 
as 
select s.DEPTNAME, 
        cast (
             (case when s.DEPTID in (2) then 
                (SELECT a.ENAME FROM 
                   (SELECT b.ENAME, b.DEPTID FROM EMPLOYEE b 
                    WHERE b.DEPTID IS NOT NULL 
                    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) a 
                  WHERE     a.DEPTID = s.DEPTID  AND ROWNUM = 1 
                )
               END)
              AS VARCHAR2(30)) "ENAME" from DEPARTMENT s;
```

But the main issue here is related to performance. For every department value in 2 we do a sort of EMPLOYEE table to get a single random ENAME. 
Is there a better way to do this ? I know sample might work but I want to achieve more randomness.

Comment: Why do you `CAST` the ENAME as a NUMBER? Isn't this supposed to be some kind of employee name?

Comment: sorry you are right,  its CAST AS VARCHAR2(30)

Comment: Your query might return the same employee multiple times. Is that intentional? Or would you rather have every employee at most once?

Comment: employee name getting repeated is fine. But it has to be random.

Answer (score 0):

First idea - join randomly numbered enames:

```
with 
  e as (select ename, deptid, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn 
          from employee where deptid = 2),
  c as (select count(1) cnt from e),
  d as (select deptname, deptid, round(dbms_random.value(1, c.cnt)) rn from department, c)
select d.deptname, e.ename from d left join e using (rn, deptid)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa125/1)</sup>

Second possible solution, which worked for me, is to create function returning random ename from table employee 
and use it in your query, but it would be probably slower.

---

**Edit** - according to comment:

If, for some reason, the first part of your statement is "fixed", then you could use this syntax:

```
create table test as 
select deptname, ename from (
  with
    e as (select ename, deptid, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) rn
            from employee where deptid = 2),
    c as (select count(1) cnt from e),
    d as (select deptname, deptid, round(dbms_random.value(1, c.cnt)) rn 
            from department cross join c)
  select d.deptname, e.ename from d left join e using (rn, deptid));
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your solution. It definitely works. If I state a different problem by saying that my <create table as select s.DEPTNAME> part is fixed and I have to write a sql query to fetch a random ename from employee table when the department is 2, how would the internal SQL query would be ? Basically I would like to call my sql query every time for the department table. Can we write this without a function ?